# Why does this replace function fail inside this lambda function but not outside it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, lambda, replace

```py
import re

input_text = "el dia 2022-12-23 o sino el dia 2022-09-23 10000-08-23"  #example

date_capture_pattern = r"([12]\d*-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)"

#input_text = re.sub(date_capture_pattern , lambda m: print(repr(m[1])) , input_text)
input_text = re.sub(date_capture_pattern , lambda m: m[1].replace("_-_", "-", 2) , input_text)

print(repr(input_text))
```

Using a `print()` I have noticed that the capture groups `m[1]` capture them correctly, since it is able to print the 3 dates correctly.

However, I feel that there is something in the syntax (in python) of the lambda function `lambda m: m[1].replace("_-_", "-", 2)` that does not allow the replacement to be possible, that is, even if the lambda function correctly receives the information, it is not able to return it.

The output that I need is that

```
"el dia 2022_-_12_-_23 o sino el dia 2022_-_09_-_23 10000_-_08_-_23"
```

It should be clarified that the code as it is in the question does not generate any error in the console, however it does not work correctly since it is simply limited to deleting the capture groups within the original string

What is wrong with that lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacement logic is off.  You should be searching `-` and replacing with `_-_`.  Use this version:

```py
input_text = "el dia 2022-12-23 o sino el dia 2022-09-23 10000-08-23"
output = re.sub(r'[12]\d*-[01]\d-[0-3]\d', lambda m: m.group().replace("-", "_-_"), input_text)
print(output)

# el dia 2022_-_12_-_23 o sino el dia 2022_-_09_-_23 10000_-_08_-_23
```

Also note that there is no need to be using a capture group here.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. One question, why you have removed the `(\D*?)` ? , Was that, in part, the problem why my code was failing?

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez Well you seem to actually want a word boundary `\b` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it works with or without adding that last part of the search pattern. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
lambda m: m[1].replace("-","_-_", 2) , input_text)
```

Order should be `"-"` then `"_-_"`

You can also achieve this with a simple string function `replace()` .

Since your input_text is a string.

```
input_text.replace("-","_-_")
```

Comment: I had not done that because the replacement condition established by the regex pattern is necessary. This is because the question is oriented to a replacement problem conditioned by search patterns (in this case I have used regex patterns as criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for the lambda function ?
A simple replace should be suffice.

##### Code:

```
input_text = "el dia 2022-12-23 o sino el dia 2022-09-23 10000-08-23"

output = input_text.replace('-', '_-_')
print(output)
```

##### Output:

```
el dia 2022_-_12_-_23 o sino el dia 2022_-_09_-_23 10000_-_08_-_23
```

Comment: `Is there a reason for the lambda function ?` ... well yes, if there could be portions of the input where we _don't_ want to replace `-`.

Comment: Yes - of course - haha - it was more of a question to the OP for clarification of specifications as the `example` did not show such a scenario.